# Help with integral and constants

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to understand an integral in a problem I am doing:

$\int\frac {du}{u} = -\int\frac {dt}{t}$

Which according to the textbook solutions gives $ln(u) = -ln(t) + ln(C)$

This seems to be done for convenience, because we get $u(t) = \frac{C}{t}$ as the final answer. But when I integrate, I get $- ln(t) -ln(C)$, which gives $u(t) = \frac{1}{Ct}$. Is it just the case that we can make the constant of integration whatever we like in problems like this? I think it is strange that the choice of constant would change the final answer.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The constant of integration is entirely arbitrary.  The two results are the same, just with different constants.  Write $$u(t)={1\over Kt}$$ and you'll see it's the same as the prior result; we just have $K={1\over C}$

Comment: we are able to redefine the integration constant however we want, for example such that $\ln(C_1)=-\ln(C_2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C$ is an arbitrary constant, if you call $C_0$ the one in the textbook solution and $C_1$ the one you get when you integrate (so we know which one is which).

$C_1=\frac{1}{C_0}$

And then $-\ln(C_1)$ becomes $+\ln(C_0)$ and the result $u(t)=\frac{1}{(C_1t)}$ becomes $u(t)=\frac{C_0}{t}$.